# Múltiplos JDK/JRE

Tags: java

Posso ter múltiplas instalações do JDK/JRE? pois tenho dois softwares diferentes sendo que um depende exclusivamente da versão 32bits (aptana studio 3) e já estou usando a versão 64 bits no eclipse.

Comment: Pode sim. É só instalar os dois ele irá buscar o correspondente que funciona com ele.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo [**este guia**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/otherFeatures/version.html#jre-jdk) da Oracle é possível.

A página também menciona:

> Várias versões do JRE pode ser executado em diferentes sessões do navegador. No entanto, várias versões não podem ser executados na mesma sessão do navegador.

Para abrir o painel de controle do Java para uma versão especifica, vá ao diretório `C:\Program Files\Java\jre<versão>\bin\` e execute o arquivo  *javacpl.exe*.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode ter várias versões do Java instaladas, mas nem sempre os softwares acham a versão correta.

A maioria vai tentar achar o Java baseado na variável de ambiente `path` do seu sistema a qual geralmente usa a variável `JAVA_HOME`. Portanto, de preferência, configure suas variáveis para a instalação mais recente que tiver.

Depois, configure especificamente cada programa para usar a versão do Java mais adequada.

O Eclipse, por exemplo, é inicializado pelo executável nativo `eclipse.exe`. Ele vai tentar pegar o Java padrão pelo `PATH`, mas também é possível editar o arquivo `eclipse.ini` para definir o caminho do JDK conforme descrito na [documentação oficial](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM). Outra alternativa para o Eclipse é colocar o JDK num subdiretório da pasta do eclipse chamado `jdk`, por exemplo

```
c:\eclipse\jdk
```

IDEs baseadas no Eclipse provavelmente vão ter a mesma configuração.